# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'registered') When i enable experimental edge runtime in my nx next project

Tags: reactjs, nginx, next.js, cloudflare

I have an nx Next 13 project and i am using cloudflare pages to deploy my site but the problem is that it runs on edge runtime environment when i enable it like:

```
//@ts-check

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const { withNx } = require('@nrwl/next/plugins/with-nx');


/**
 * @type {import('@nrwl/next/plugins/with-nx').WithNxOptions}
 **/


const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    runtime: 'experimental-edge',
    appDir: false
  },
  nx: {
    // Set this to true if you would like to to use SVGR
    // See: https://github.com/gregberge/svgr
    svgr: true,
  },
  presets: ['next/babel'],
  env: {
    customKey: 'here-env',
  },
  images: {
    domains: [
      'cdn.pixabay.com',
      'localhost',
      'pixabay.com',
      'jsdevs-attachments.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com',
      'lh3.googleusercontent.com',
      'lh5.googleusercontent.com',
      'lh4.googleusercontent.com',
    ],
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'jsdevs-attachments.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com',
        port: '',
        pathname: '',
      },
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'lh3.googleusercontent.com',
        port: '',
        pathname: '',
      },
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'https://1zrfq19u.directus.app',
        port: '',
        pathname: '',
      },
    ],
  },
  swcMinify: false,
};

module.exports = withNx(nextConfig);
```

It gives the following error when i start the next server
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'registered')

At first it was next 12 then i upgraded to next 13 and upgraded all the packages for the nx project but i have no luck in any of them

Comment: Same issue here